# ROS2: How to synchronize two topics with message_filters and a defined QoS

Tags: ros2, message-filters, synchronization

I try to synchronize two ROS2 topic using message_filter (sync_policies/approximate_time):

- a *sensor_msgs::msgs::Imu* from an Imu
- a *sensor_msgs::msgs::PointCloud2* from a radar, which is published with the QoS rclcpp::SensorDataQoS()

By default, the subscriber of each topic is Reliable, which is incompatible with the pointcloud2 publisher QoS which is Best effort.

I suppose that keep the SensorDataQoS() is the best for datas from a radar or a lidar. So, how is it possible to synchronize the pointcloud2 topic with an another topic, keeping the QoS? Is there a way to specify the QoS in subscriber with message_filter? Or should I use an another way?

My code:

*Synchro.hpp*

```
using namespace message_filters;
using namespace sensor_msgs;

class Synchro : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
    explicit Synchro(const rclcpp::NodeOptions &options = rclcpp::NodeOptions());
    ~Synchro() {};

  protected:
   //callback
    void topic_callback(const msg::PointCloud2::ConstSharedPtr& msg_pc, const msg::Imu::ConstSharedPtr& msg_imu);

    // ROS2 subscriber and related topic name
    Subscriber<msg::PointCloud2> subscriber_pc_;
    Subscriber<msg::Imu> subscriber_imu_;

   using ApproxSync = sync_policies::ApproximateTime<msg::PointCloud2, msg::Imu>;
    typedef Synchronizer<ApproxSync> Sync;
    std::shared_ptr<Sync> sync_;
};
```

*Synchro.cpp*

```
using std::placeholders::_1;
using std::placeholders::_2;
using namespace sensor_msgs;

Synchro::Synchro(const rclcpp::NodeOptions& options) : Node("synchro_node",options) 
{
  //sub creation
  subscriber_pc_.subscribe(this, param_topic_pointcloud_in);
  subscriber_imu_.subscribe(this, param_topic_imu_in);

  ////The following line is my way to create a subscriber with a specific QoS but this declaration doesn't build**
  //subscriber_pc_ = this->create_subscription<msg::PointCloud2>(param_topic_pointcloud_in,rclcpp::SensorDataQoS(), this, _1);

  //Synchro callback
  sync_.reset(new Sync(ApproxSync(100), subscriber_pc_, subscriber_imu_));
  sync_->setMaxIntervalDuration(rclcpp::Duration(3,0));
  sync_->registerCallback(std::bind(&Synchro::topic_callback, this, _1, _2)); 
}

void Synchro::topic_callback(const msg::PointCloud2::ConstSharedPtr& msg_pc, const msg::Imu::ConstSharedPtr& msg_imu)
{
  //my callback actions
}
```